# How to do database sizing?

Tags: sql-server-2008

does anyone have any idea how to do database sizing for SQL Server 2008 R2? Is there any books or sample excel templates that i can reference to use for database sizing estimation? What are the factors to consider etc for say 5 years growth rate etc

Thanks alot

Comment: The database auto-grows.  Try here first for a cursory introduction to database growth:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a blog post](http://sqlserverdiaries.com/blog/index.php/2011/05/estimating-the-size-of-an-sql-server-database/) that has links to Excel worksheets for both SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008.